# Is there a drawback to importing modules to group classes together, instead of putting all the classes in one file in Python?

Tags: python, class, import, module

I have a module that I wrote called "datasource" that houses a number of classes. I use this module to access some data from SQL databases as well as SNMP calls to devices.

Right now, this is one very large file. Are there any drawbacks to breaking each class into it's own py module and simply import them in the datasource module?

i.e. datasource.py now:

```
#!/local/bin/python3
class Our_db:
    # A bunch of code to access our SQL database

class Their_db:
    # A bunch of code to access another SQL database

class MySNMP:
    # A bunch of code to retrieve data via SNMP
```

i.e. datasource updated with each class in it's own .py file:

```
#!/local/bin/python3

import Our_db
import Their_db
import MySNMP
```

If I do this, can I still import datasource and access the classes as if they were all in one file? I don't want to break any code that uses this module, but I do want to simplify maintenance.

Thanks!

Comment: No drawbacks and if anything it is recommended to break your code into more readable chunks!

Comment: I have found one small drawback... I lose the reference to "self", since the classes are imported as modules and not classes. This means it won't work with my existing code.

Comment: if you do `from Our_db import *` etc... things should still be imported as classes and retain references to `self` etc...

Comment: if you put class `Our_db` in file `Our_db.py` then you have module `Our_db` and class `Our_db.Our_db()`

Comment: I am prepending my file names with an underscore so as not to confuse the module with the class. This seems to work fine.

Comment: @Calab _I lose the reference to "self", since the classes are imported as modules and not classes._ What do you mean?

Comment: If I had a function in my class, the self reference didn't work in the function definition. I think it was my mistake though as I have it working fine now.

Comment: Classes are not imported as modules; you just appear to have each class in a module of the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a script like this, `script.py`:

```
class Our_db:
    def m(self):
        print("Hello!")

our_db = Our_db()
our_db.m()
```

You can still refactor your class definitions out and if you are worried about other changes in your code do just make sure the class is still imported with the same name, e.g., `ourdb.py`:

```
class Our_db:
    def m(self):
        print("Hello!")
```

and `script.py`:

```
from ourdb import Our_db
our_db = Our_db()
our_db.m()
```

Whether to split or not split is a question of readability and maintenance. You want to strike balance between too many tiny module and few jumbo modules. I generally try to keep mine under 1000 lines and  whatever a logical grouping would be (so that I or anyone else reading it later can find related things without too much head scratching).